# Add some column to query

Tags: php, laravel-5, query-builder

If you add another `select()` clause to query build chain it will be replace the previous one. How to add some db column to a previously configured query? This is in particular useful in defining the query scopes.

Answer (score 1):

There should be addSelect() function available.

Reference can be found here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#selects